# Is Clark (Philippines) worth a visit for 4 days

Tags: budget, planning, philippines, manila, crk

I am planning different options for a 4 day trip. I got cheap flights for a place called Clark in Philippines from Singapore. But I don't know much about Clark and Philippines. I want to know what are the places I can visit If I go to Clark.?

Comment: You will get a better response if you indicate what research you have already made, and if you specify what kinds of thing would make a trip worth your while. Otherwise, it is impossible for anyone to give a suitable answer. At the very minimum, have you looked at http://www.visitclark.com/ ?

Comment: I don't know why you accepted Peter's answer which is very subjective for a person who has a little knowledge of the place. Clark is one of the best places in the Philippines and has one of the nicest airport (better than the airports in Manila). It would be best to go to there during Philippine International Hot-Air Balloon Fiesta.

Comment: Peter at least provided some basis for his “subjective” assessment. How is Clark “one of the best places in the Philippines”? What can you see or do there? I guess this fiesta is fine if you are into hot air balloons but surely, most people don't travel to foreign countries solely to stay 4 days in a nice airport and see hot air balloons…

Comment: Did you check the usual places before asking here? [WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Angeles_City) • [Clark's homepage](http://www.visitclark.com/) • [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Attractions-g3336531-Activities-Clark_Freeport_Zone_Angeles_City_Central_Luzon_Region_Luzon.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clark itself is not worth visiting. Until 1991 the area used to be an American air force base: '[Clark Air Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark_Air_Base)', now its an airport which some budget airlines use. The area is also a free trading zone: [Clark Freeport Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clark_Freeport_Zone), but not really interesting for tourists, unless you are into old US military installations.

The main reason to fly to Clark, is that is usually cheaper than flying to the main Manila airport, but you don't stay there, you move on to Manila (60km south) or to the Northern parts of Luzon.

There are direct buses from outside the terminal to Manila, but you can also walk to the main road take a [jeepney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepney) to the next town and then a regular bus to Manila, the second option is cheaper but will take longer.

Manila is a big city with some sites, but you may not need 4 days unless you want to go shopping which should be cheaper than in Singapore.

Alternatively you could head north, there are some awesome rice terraces around [Banaue](http://wikitravel.org/en/Banaue), Batad and Bontac. There is a lot of great nature in the hills of Northern Lazon.

Comment: Why categorically claim Clark itself not to be worth visiting? There are many foreign visitors to Angeles City, specifically, which is right next to Clark airport, with dozens of hotels and bars catering to them. If there were no tourist attractions whatsoever, those would not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Clark US Air force Base was used a lot at the time of the Vietnam war. It was a stop off for American GI's debrifing and transition solders back into the world as we new it then. It has nothing much to do there, so don't expect much to do if you go there.